# TypeScript : how to declare an enum across multiple files?

Tags: typescript, enums

file AppActions.ts

```ts
export enum Actions {
  START = 0,
  RECOVER,
  FIRST_RUN,
  ALERT_NETWORK,
  LOADING_DATA,
  RECEIVED_DATA,
  GO_OFFLINE,
  GO_ONLINE
}
```

file PlayerActions.ts

```ts
import {Actions} from "./AppActions.ts"
enum Actions {
  HEAL_SINGLE,
  HIT_SINGLE
}
```

Normally, regarding [this manual](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html) it should throw an error at compile time. But:

1- the PlayerActions.ts does not seem to extend the existing Actions enum. (in WebStorm `import {Actions} from "./AppActions.ts"` is in grey)

2- the compiler does not throw any errors.

So what is the right way to declare Enum across multiple files?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to have partial enums in Typescript since the Transpiler builds the global types per each "export."

One possible solution might be merging two (multiple) enums as follows:

In the first file you have:

```
export enum Action_first_half{
   START = 0,
   RECOVER,
   ...
}
```

In another file you have:

```
export enum Action_second_half {
   HEAL_SINGLE,
   HIT_SINGLE
}
```

Then in another file, you can have:

```
const Actions = { ...Action_second_half , ...Action_first_half};
type Actions = typeof Actions ;
```

Now, you can treat the "Actions" as if it is a regular enum:

```
public const action: Actions = Actions.START;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `enum` as a `global` value like below.

In the first file

```js
    declare global {
      export enum Actions {
        START = 0,
        RECOVER = 1,
      }
    }
```

In the second file

```js
    declare global {
      export enum Actions {
        HEAL_SINGLE = 2,
        HIT_SINGLE = 3,
      }
    }
```

Then you can simply access enum value like `Actions.START` or `Actions.HEAL_SINGLE` in any file